# split a string values in column using python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Consider a sample dataframe

```
df11 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1'+'_'+'2']})
```

I want to split column values to list in the respective rows and convert into integer. I am using the below code, the output values are in the form of string. How can i convert into integer

```
df11["Timetaken"] = df11['A'].str.split('_')
```

current output column i have is like below

[image]

I want to convert the string of values to integer or float

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: i have added a snippet of output i have. all i want is to convert the string of values inside list in each row to integer/float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list comprehension, simply add:

```
[int(x) for x in df11['A'].str.split('_')]
```

This will give you a list of integers.

---

For the edited question, you can change the type of those values using

```
df11['Timetaken'] = df11['Timetaken'].apply(lambda x: [int(y) for y in x])
```

Comment: i have a huge dataframe with column whose value is a number joined in the formed of string. how can i add use your answer to convert entire column into comma seperated list of integers

Comment: @SoKu Please see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand=True` then use `astype` and use `agg` like below:

**As `int`**

```
>>> df['Timetaken'] =  df11['A'].str.split('_', expand=True).astype(int).apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)
```

**As `float`**

```
>>> df['Timetaken'] =  df11['A'].str.split('_', expand=True).astype(float).apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)

>>> df
    Timetaken
0   [9.0, 6.0, 36.0]
1   [3.0, 1.0]
2   [9.0, 2.0]
3   [6856.0, 4870.0]
4   [6864.0]
5   [6873.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only pandas methods like so:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Timetaken": [
            "9.0_6.0_36.0",
            "3.0_1.0",
            "9.0_2.0",
            "6856.0_4870.0",
            "6864.0",
            "6873.0",
        ]
    }
)

df["Timetaken"] = (
    df["Timetaken"]
    .str.split("_")
    .explode()
    .astype("float")
    .astype("int")
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(list)
)
```

Which will:

- `split` the strings
- Explode them into separate rows
- Convert them to numeric (`.astype('float').astype('int')`)
- finally put them back into lists (`.groupby(...).apply(...)`)